SSL error with zammad-py however curl works
The access to my zammad system works with curl. The following request results in a correct answer:
curl -H "Authorization: Token token=<user-token>" https://<url>/api/v1/users

However, the equivalent Python implementation zammad_py don't work.
from zammad_py import ZammadAPI

client = ZammadAPI(url=HOST, http_token=api_token)

# Example: Access all users
this_page = client.user.all()
for user in this_page:
    print(user)

The previous python code results in an ssl-error.
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=<url>, port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /users/me (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)')))

In addition, curl -v https://<url> shows no errors or warnings.
Does anyone have an idea?

I found the solution, zammad-py does not support ssl so far. However, I added an SSLAdapter to the zammad-py code and now it works. I created also an issue (enter link description here) for this improvement.
